# Strange behaviour from CFStringCompareWithOptions

Tags: c++, macos, core-foundation, cfstring

I'm trying to find out exactly how I can match the first `n` characters of a string with another. Here's some code I've got at the moment:

```
CFStringRef myStringRef = CFSTR("hello");
CFStringRef otherStringRef = CFSTR("helloworld");

CFIndex cmpChars = CFStringGetLength(myStringRef);

CFComparisonResult res = CFStringCompareWithOptions(myStringRef, otherStringRef, CFRangeMake(0, cmpChars), kCFCompareCaseInsensitive);

printf("Res: %i\n", (int)res);
```

I get the value of `res` as `-1`, meaning 'less than' according to the documentation. Surely though, since I specified the range to match it should only take that range into account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation could be clearer, but the range is applied only to the first string, not the second.  [Here's a link to an old mailing list message.](http://lists.apple.com/archives/carbon-dev/2005/Aug/msg00525.html)  What you can't tell from the archive, but I know from my personal archive, is that the guy who said so was an Apple engineer.

To do what you want, you may need to use `CFStringCreateWithSubstring` too.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the same is true of NSString's `compare:options:range:`. https://gist.github.com/4325317